# Android Firebase Auth with Vkontakte OAuth

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, vk

I'm trying to integrate Firebase auth with custom auth through VK (vk.com) service, but it's failed with next error:

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation. [ Invalid assertion format. 3 dot separated segments required. ]

My code is below:

```
public void onLogin(@NotNull VKAccessToken vkAccessToken) {
  mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(vkAccessToken.getAccessToken()).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.d("LoginU", "signInWithCustomToken:success");
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        int i = 1;
    } else {
        Log.w("LoginU", "signInWithVKToken:failure", task.getException());
    }
```

Comment: It looks like VK is not returning a valid JWT.

Comment: Is any standard ways to do that (mean converting from VK to Firebase JWT)?